# How to apply Windows Forms Control to WPF Custom Control Library?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I'm trying to encapsulate Windows Forms Control (from previous version of project) to WPF Custom Control Library. Because I want to use it in future Wpf applications (like drag&drop from toolbox in VS). I successfully done this: [WinForms in Wpf App](http://www.example.com/). Do you know site/or tutorials where this things are explained?

What I got: .dll with WinForms control, Wpf Custom Control Library project (to place WinForms control) and Wpf Aplication.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, as a start, you can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @SonerGönül Thanks for editing my post. Beside that do you have any suggestions about my question ?

Answer (score 0):

What SonerGönül is refering to, is that if you read the links he points out.
You can see you should have done this steps better:

- *Do your homework*

  There is plenty of examples all over on how to achieve what you want to do.
  Search on Google something like "how to host winforms in wpf"
  You will get plenty of links like: 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx
  Even questions done in this site in the past.
- *Be specific, Make it relevant to others*

  You need to make a more clear question. Read your question as if someone else is the person who wrote it, and think if you would be able to understand it properly.

People in this site wants to see you have worked towards solving your problem, therefore you can mention things you already have done, and make a specific question.
Like "I implemented what this website suggest but I am getting this exception"

**To answer your question**

I really like this website: [Mixing WPF and WinForms](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/)

Because it gives you a nice both side explanation of how Mixing WPF and Winforms works, with examples.

Comment: Ad.1 I always first looking for an answer on various sites, and I tried few examples.
Ad.2 I think that was written good, because English is not my native language :)

And last, yes i found this site and i was manage to add WinForms control into Custom Control, and then drag and drop this custom control into my WPF application.

Now i strangle how to get context of winforms control in wpf application.

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that you want to use a Winforms control and you want to use it in WPF, and then you asked about websites that show you how to do that. That is why someone downvoted your question, and why SonerGönül and me suggested you to read the FAQ. Since you already have a working example, maybe you can add some code to your question? When you say you want to get the context of winforms control in WPF? Do you want to get data from the WinformsControl? is that what you want? Maybe if you write in pseudo-code what you want to achieve, it would help.